# How to choose which network adapter a program uses?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

My laptop has an integrated WiFi card which is connected to network A, but I also have an external WiFi adapter that is plugged in via USB and connected to network B. These are 2 seperate WiFi networks with 2 different bandwidths.

I opened Chrome and started downloading a file. Task manager shows network activity on the integrated adapter. On the side, I opened another program to download some files, but it is also using the same adapter, thereby splitting the bandwidth.

Now, what I'm wondering is how does Windows decide which adapter to use? Also,  is there a way to assign programs to adapters?

Comment: Normal OS behaviour is not to assign a network adaptor to a program. Instead it will assign it to a network, a to a specific host or to 'default'. There are 'hacks' around it (e.g. forcebind.exe), or you could start a VM and passthough one wireless NIC to the VM and start one program on the main computer and one on the VM.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/570439/setting-a-static-route-for-a-specific-network-adapter-with-two-network-adapters

Comment: @Excaliber I suspect that wont work how you want it though, its more for fixed networks (traffic to office over A, all other traffic over B), you want dynamic load balancing which is a different setup.

Comment: @Linef4ult I'm surprised how complicated this is ...